# prove or disprove that there exist linearly independent vectors $v,w \in \Bbb C^3$ such that $Av=Aw=0$

Tags: matrices

Let $\omega$ be a complex number such that $\omega^3 =1$, but $\omega \neq 1$. If $$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&\omega&\omega^2\\ \omega&\omega^2&1 \\ \omega^2&\omega&1\end{pmatrix}\quad $$ . Then prove or disprove that there exist linearly independent vectors $v,w \in \Bbb C^3$ such that $Av = Aw = 0$

My Attempt:

Let $v^T = (1, 1, 1)^T$ and $w^T = (a, b, c)^T$ such that $Av = 0$ and $Aw = 0$ with $(a+b\omega+c\omega^2,a\omega+b\omega^2+c,a\omega^2+b\omega+c)^T =(0,0,0)^T$. I unable to solve this. Please help me.

Comment: Hint: your question is asking about the nullspace of $A$. What is the typical procedure to find the nullspace of a matrix?

Comment: $Dim(Null(A)) = 3-rank(A) = 3-2= 1$. It means $A$ has only one linearly independent eigen vector. Am I right ?

Comment: That is the rank-nullity theorem. Not exactly what I had in mind. Instead, to find $Null(A)$, consider the system $Ax=0$ and solve using row reduction. Then, find the space of vectors satisfying this equation. Let me know if this helps. If not I can write a full solution in a bit.

Comment: In "My Attempt" on solving , I get $a = b = c$. So $w^T = (a,a,a)^T$ and when $a = 1$ then we get $v^T = (1,1,1)^T$. So dimension of null space is 1. Am I right ?

Comment: Ah yes, exactly! Sorry I misread something. Showing that $dim(Null(A))=1$ disproves the existence of two LI vectors.

Comment: I learnt something more when you misread.

Comment: glad to hear. If you were asked to find the particular vectors $v, w$, the method described above is how you should proceed (:

Answer (score 2):

There are not two linear independent solutions, because the dimension of the Null space is 1 ($dim(A)-rank(A)=3-2$), this means that $Av=0$ has only one linear independent solution.

If you want to know how to get a basis for that null space, you can do the following:

Consider the three equations that comes from $Aw=0$:
$$ a+bw+cw^2=0 $$
$$ aw+bw^2+c=0$$
$$aw^2 +bw+c=0$$
now, if you multiply the first equation by w (and remembering that $w^3=1$), you will get the second equation, so the first equation could be neglected (it doesn't aport any new information), and if you take the second equation and substract the third you will obtain the following:
$$a(w-w^2) -b(w-w^2)=0 $$
which means that $a=b$.
To get $c$ you can obtain it from any equation which gives:
$$c=-a(w+w^2)$$
And finally, a the vector that generates the null space is $(1,1,-(w+w^2))^T$, its norm is $\sqrt{2+|w+w^2|^2}=\sqrt{4+2Re(w)}=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: One step missing at the end, which is to use that $\,\omega\,$ is a complex cube root of unity so $\,\omega+\omega^2=-1\,$.

Comment: ohh I totally skipped that, it is $Re(w) = -1/2$, I gonna edit that inmediately